# What is the difference between DynaActionForm and ActionForm?

Tags: java, struts, struts-config, actionform

What is the difference between `DynaActionForm` and `ActionForm` ?

Someone said `DynaActionForm` is not really dynamic since you still have to restart the server after you **re-configured** the properties in the `struts-config.xml` file (or else modifications won't be picked up)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of **`ActionForm`**,

**We have to provide `setters` and `getters` whenever user adds a control.** The same process is repeated again and again when user creates a view.

But, in case of **`DynaActionForm`**

It eliminates this burden and creates the form bean itself. This way user **don't have to write `setters` and `getters`.** No bean class is required for the **`DynaActionForm`** and we will declare the form beans as **`DynaActionForm`** type in `struts-confing.xml`. We will declare the properties and their type in the `struts-config.xml`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_0.dtd">

<struts-config>

  <!-- ========== Form Bean Definitions ================= -->
  <form-beans>

    <form-bean      name="submitForm"
                    type="hansen.playground.SubmitForm"/>

  </form-beans>

  <!-- ========== Action Mapping Definitions ============ -->
  <action-mappings>

    <action   path="/submit"
              type="hansen.playground.SubmitAction"
              name="submitForm"
              input="/submit.jsp"
              scope="request">
    <forward name="success" path="/submit.jsp"/>          
    <forward name="failure" path="/submit.jsp"/>          
    </action>

  </action-mappings>

</struts-config>
```

**Update**

> `struts-config.xml` has two sections: the **form-beans** section, that lists the ActionForm beans, and the **action-mappings**.The mapping of the request (**`MyActionForm.do`**) to a specific
>   Action and ActionForm class is done in the struts-config.xml file.